# Pointwise convergence implies weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Theorem 12 from Royden, 4th edition:

Let $f_n$ be a bounded sequence in $L^{p}$ for $1<p<\infty$ such that
$ f_n \xrightarrow{\text{P.C.A.E}} f$. This implies $ f_n \xrightarrow{\text{w}} f$ in $L^{p}$.

The text uses Vitali convergence theorem and Uniform Integrability to prove the result. I would like to prove this without these concepts.

My attempt:

Since simple functions are dense in $L^{p}$. To check for weak convergence I only need to check if for sets of finite measure $A$, that

$$ \int_{A} f_{n} \rightarrow  \int_{A} f$$

By Egoroff's theorem since $A$ has finite measure and $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $A$. Then $f_{n}$ converges almost uniformly to $f$ in $A$. I am unable to proceed from here. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to bound the integrand on the small set provided by Egoroff theorem. The idea is to use Fatou lemma, to get
$$
\int |f|^p \le \liminf \int |f_n|^p \le M^p
$$
due to boundedness.

Take $\epsilon>0$. By Egoroff theorem, there is $B\subset A$
such that $f_n \to f$ on $B$ and $\mu( A\setminus B)<\epsilon$.
Then
$$
\left| \int_A (f_n-f) \right| \le \left| \int_B (f_n-f) \right| + \epsilon^{1-\frac1p} \|f_n-f\|_{L^p}.
$$
Passing to the limit $n\to \infty$
$$
\limsup \left| \int_A (f_n-f) \right| \le 0 + \epsilon^{1-\frac1p} 2M.
$$
As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $\int_A (f_n-f)  \to 0$ follows.